# Is it possible to add content assist feature with text widget?

Tags: java, text, eclipse-plugin, swt, text-editor

I am enhanching one form based multipage editor. In which, swt controls are used as UI elements for some pages and xtexteditor as text editor for one other page which has feature of displaying content assist when we press ctrl + space keys together.

I want to add the same content assist feature with swt text widgets.

Que 1: Is it possible to add content assist feature with text widget?

Que 2: If we can add content assist feature with text widget, then which type of editor (texteditor/celleditor/any other) should i use with text widget?

I tried to use textcelleditor(jface celleditor) with my swt text widget and I went through many articles but they all are using textcelleditor(jface celleditor) with swt tableviewer.

Links:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.eclipse.jface.viewers/TableViewersetCellEditorsCellEditorarg0.htm

http://javafind.appspot.com/model?id=318036

http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/Eclipse-RCP-Comboboxes-inside-a-JFace-TableViewer100.html

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53044.html

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/171575/

Can any one help me on this point that "how can i add content assist (xtexteditor based or any other like jface celleditor) with text widgets".

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A list of the articles you already tried would be helpful.

Comment: You could use `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer` to display the text. This is the standard class used by editors to support content assist (and other things).

Comment: @greg449: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you please give me more information about usage of org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer. Any example would be fine.

Comment: @Baz: Added reference links.